# Cannot freeze rotation on an object that has translate function on it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a game, same as the games where rockets follows a plane to destroy it. I have a problem at the rocket. It is 3D and when the game start the rocket is rotating 90 degrees and I don't understand why, and how could be fixed.

I tried to use constrains from rigidbody, in inspector, but those didn't worked.

this is the script that controls the rocket.

```
public class Move_missle_lookAt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform mTarget;
    public float mSpeed ;
    const float EPSILON = 0.1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(mTarget.position);

        if ((transform.position - mTarget.position).magnitude > EPSILON)
              transform.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, mSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: the freeze rotation only applies to the specifics if you use the rigidbody, by applying force..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your model is oriented incorrectly to start with. So, althought it appears to be rotated, it's actually in its native orientation.

After you call `LookAt()`, rotate the transform by 90° to compensate.

Comment: Thank you so much, I stayed so much on this thing that I can not believe it